# How set order MIN_VALUE to filter in web.xml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, web.xml, servlet-filters

I have a custom  filter like this:

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean captchaFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CaptchaFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/login");
    registration.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    registration.setName("captchaFilter");
    return registration;
}
```

And I want put this filter in my `web.xml` (without Spring Boot) but how could I set order to this? I want to set order to `MIN_VALUE` because I want that work before `springSecurityFilterChain`.

Comment: filters in web.xml are executed in the order they are declared. Just add the filter before the security one... No need to use ordering.

Comment: @M.Deinum hi thanks. it is not work correctly because  order of springSecurityFilterChain is low value.

Comment: Order has nothing to do with it. As stated filter execution order in web.xml is as defined... No ordering of Spring will be able to interfere with that.